# Automatically add a Join statement in findBy magic method

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony2 / Doctrine2.

I'm trying to override the BaseEntityRepository Class so the magic findBy method automatically adds a JOIN on a "translations" relation. It was easy to do in Symfony 1.4/Doctrine 1, because it was manipulating a Doctrine_Query object, so I simply had to $query->addJoin() and it did the trick.

Unfortunately, in Doctrine 2 you only receive an array of criteria as parameter, and that's where I'm stucked.

I got many entities which have a one-to-many relationship with a translation entity.

For exemple : Section as a one-to-many relationship with SectionTranslation

The goal is to retrieve only the "active" sections (active is in SectionTranslation) when using SectionRepository->findAll(); (or even findBy).

The wanted DQL result is : Select * from Section INNER JOIN SectionTranslation ON Section.id = SectionTranslation.translatable_id WHERE SectionTranslation.locale = $locale AND SectionTranslation.active = 1;

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be adding event listener for particular entity and particular method.